# Check if cell contains text from a list and display that value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get a formula together that will look through a column and find if that particular cell contains any text from another column and if so, use that value.

For example, in col A I have the strings I need to look within:

```
abc123
def456
def789
ghi123
```

and in col B I have the values I want to look for within col A:

```
abc
ghi
```

I'm currently using this formula in col C to find out if any of the values in col B are within any of the values in col A:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$2&"*"))>0,"YES","NO")
```

This is working great as it's coming back with "YES" for 'abc123' and 'ghi123' and "NO" for the rest (as 'def' isn't in my list).

However, instead of just saying "YES" or "NO", I'd like it to actually put in the value it's found.  So for 'abc123' and 'ghi123' I'd like it to say 'abc' and 'ghi' in col C.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand the current formula you're using in relation to your description. For a start, by using entire column references, each instance of that formula is being forced to calculate over more than a million cells, an astonishing amount. I'm actually surprised your workbook hasn't ground to a halt. Do you really need to check all one million-plus cells in column B as to whether they are found in each entry? Secondly, did the post editor perhaps remove some of your formula? Should ""&B:B&"" perhaps have asterisks in there? Or did you intend spacing here, i.e. " "&B:B&" "?

Comment: What's more, if you are using asterisks, I'm interested to know how you could obtain ANY results of "NO" with that formula, since any blank entry in column B (I'm sure there must be some!) will register as a count within any string, since =COUNTIF(A1,"**") is always 1 if A1 contains a text value.

Comment: sorry, I had put in the original formula I had started using and not the updated one - I've edited it so now it only looks at the range of values that are populated in col B

Comment: wouldn't you just change `"YES"` to `A1` as that's what you're looking up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$2&"*"),$B$1:$B$2),"No Match")
```